# Electron Composition

Tags: electrons

When you have a sparking wire, electricity in the form of electrons are coming out of the wire. The electron sparks then dissipate in the air. If the electron is fundamental and not made up of anything else, then what is it dissipating into when it does? It's not like it simply disappears or goes off in a direction, so I believe it must be breaking down into smaller particles than the electron and dispersing them at great speeds.

What do electrons turn into when they dissipate into energy in the air?

Comment: Your premise is wrong. "A sparking wire" does not imply "electrons are coming out of the wire."

Comment: Air also is filled with many atoms/molecules (e.g., Oxygen, Nitrogen, etc), and those atoms contain electrons. For more information you can google "dielectric breakdown."

Comment: You are correct that an electron is a fundamental particle. It is a point particle with no internal structure.

Comment: Personal theories are off-topic here, so you might want to edit your question to ask something like “What is happening when a wire sparks?”. Otherwise, it may get closed as non-mainstream physics.

Answer (score 4):

Sparks are formed two ways: 1) when dust particles and tiny pieces of wire carrying the electricity get set on fire by the heat of the spark at the surface of the wire, and 2) when the electric fields at the tip of the spark are strong enough to ionize the air molecules and render the air electrically conductive.

The sparks caused by burning material are extinguished after all the flammables are consumed.

The ionization is extinguished when the electrical power stored in the wire is used up. Then the molecules reunite with their stripped-off electrons and any excess electrons that were ejected from the wire cause chemical reactions in the air which create highly reactive chemicals like ozone and so-called "free radicals". These things then give rise to a cascade of successive chemical reactions in the air.

All of this happens without splitting any of the electrons themselves apart- which is in any case impossible because there is nothing to "split apart" inside an electron- because it has zero size.

Comment: *There is nothing to "split apart" inside an electron- because it has zero size.* A muon also has zero size, and there is nothing “inside” it, but it *can* decay (i.e., change into) into an electron and neutrinos. An electron can’t do the same because there is no lighter charged lepton for it to decay to; if there were, it could and would.